# mysql - importing large Tablespace: Lost connection during query

Tags: innodb, mysql-5.7, tablespaces, timeout, query-timeout

iam trying to recover innodb table which has 1.5M rows from ibd file ( 5.5 GB )

this is the exact steps i do:

1. getting create table query using mysqlfrm command
2. create the table
3. Alter Table  discard tablespace
4. moving the new tablespace to the db directory
5. Alter Table  import tablespace;

and i'm getting this error after 5 minutes :-

ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query
my.cnf:

```
[client]
port=3307
[mysql]
no-beep

[mysqld]
max_allowed_packet=8M
innodb_buffer_pool_size=511M
innodb_log_file_size=500M
innodb_log_buffer_size=800M
net_read_timeout=28800
net_write_timeout=28800
connect_timeout=28800
wait_timeout=28800
open_files_limit=100000
innodb_open_files=100000
delayed_insert_timeout=28800
innodb_lock_wait_timeout=28800
slave_net_timeout=28800

skip-grant-tables
port=3307
datadir=D:\dbrecover\_home_db_\home\db
default-storage-engine=INNODB
sql-mode="STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
log-output=FILE
general-log=0
general_log_file="WIN-36LFCDISVVC.log"
slow-query-log=1
slow_query_log_file="WIN-36LFCDISVVC-slow.log"
long_query_time=10
log-error="WIN-36LFCDISVVC.err"
relay_log="WIN-36LFCDISVVC-relay"
server-id=1
report_port=3307
lower_case_table_names=2
secure-file-priv="C:/ProgramData/MySQL/MySQL Server 5.7/Uploads"
max_connections=151
table_open_cache=2000
tmp_table_size=123M
thread_cache_size=10
myisam_max_sort_file_size=100G
myisam_sort_buffer_size=236M
key_buffer_size=8M
read_buffer_size=64K
read_rnd_buffer_size=256K
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=1
innodb_thread_concurrency=9
innodb_autoextend_increment=64
innodb_buffer_pool_instances=8
innodb_concurrency_tickets=5000
innodb_old_blocks_time=1000
innodb_open_files=300
innodb_stats_on_metadata=0
innodb_file_per_table=1
innodb_checksum_algorithm=0
back_log=80
flush_time=0
join_buffer_size=256K
max_connect_errors=100
sort_buffer_size=256K
table_definition_cache=1400
binlog_row_event_max_size=8K
sync_master_info=10000
sync_relay_log=10000
sync_relay_log_info=10000
```

is there any way to import it ??

Comment: `net_read_timeout` and `net_write_timeout` are set to 600, which is 5 minutes, so I think this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34369376/mysql-what-is-mysqls-wait-timeout-net-read-timeout-and-net-write-timeout-varia might be an answer 

Comment: @Luuk
I increased ( net_read_timeout , net_write_timeout , connect_timeout , wait_timeout and delayed_insert_timeout ) to 28800
but nothing changed .. i am getting the same error after 5 - 13 minutes

Comment: Additional information request. Post on pastebin.com and share the links.
RAM size, # cores of your MySQL Host server 
A) complete (not edited) my.cnf or my.ini  
From SSH login root, Text results of: 
B) SHOW GLOBAL STATUS;    after 24 hours UPTIME, if possible.
C) SHOW GLOBAL VARIABLES; 
D) SHOW FULL PROCESSLIST;
AND Optional very helpful information, if available includes - 
htop OR top OR mytop for active apps, 
ulimit -a       for a linux/unix list of limits, 
iostat -xm 5 3 for IOPS by device and core/cpu count, 
for server workload tuning analysis to provide suggestions.

Comment: Does this case already solve? Im getting same issue here my file size is 575kb only..